# ** File not found /boot/uImage ** When using Angstrom Pre-built Images on BeagleBoneBlack Rev C

Tags: u-boot, beagleboneblack, load, angstrom, mmc

I'm trying to boot my BeagleBone Black into Angstrom using pre-built images found [here](https://github.com/BharatRaj-G/EmbeddedLinux/tree/master/BeagleBone_LinuxBuild/AngstromDistribution/Angstrom-v2012.12%20-%202013.06.20). 
My SD card has two partitions `BOOT` & `ROOTFS`, and was formatted according to the procedures found [here](https://www.armhf.com/boards/beaglebone-black/bbb-sd-install/).

[image]

Below are the contents of both partitions:

[image: contents of BOOT & ROOTFS]

The `lost+found` folder was the result of formatting the SD card and I haven't been able to delete it. I don't think this would cause u-boot to hang.

However when booting, u-boot repeatedly tells me that it can't find `/boot/uImage` & `/boot/am335x-boneblack.dtb`:

[image: boot-up sequence]

The first of the following 2 images is my `uEnv.txt`, it uses `load mmc 0:2` to both load these files. The second image is the result after attempting to use `ext4load mmc 0:2` since the ROOTFS partition is formatted as ext4:

[image: uEnv.txt] 
[image: entering uboot and using ext4load]

The ROOTFS (mmc 0:2) partition contains the rootfile system, but when I attempt to list the contents of the `/boot` directory u-boot returns nothing. When I had the SD card plugged into my comp and mounted. I attempted to `ls` the `/boot` directory and denied permission despite using `sudo`.

[image: listing the contents of my ROOTFS partition (mmc 0:2)]

Why can't uboot locate the uImage and dtb files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are the classic symptoms of an old U-Boot trying to use a modern ext4 fs that has incompatible features.  You need to run mkfs.ext4 with `-O ^64bit,^metadata_csum` for a U-Boot of that era to work with the filesystem.

Comment: Thanks @Tom Rini, that made it work, I reformatted my ROOTFS partition using your suggestion and that allowed for the kernel to boot. I have a lot to learn still.

Comment: FYI - "lost+found" that I mentioned in my second image, is most likely a partially recovered file that fsck found while fixing my uSD card. See the second paragraph in the [Use](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fsck) section of the fsck wiki-page.